# Proving the equality of function application on two equivalent functions

Tags: coq

How would I prove the following in Coq?

```
Variables f g : nat->nat.
Hypothesis Hfg : forall x, f x = g x.
Variable F : (nat->nat)->nat.
Goal F f = F g.
```

We have two functions, `f` and `g`, that are not necessarily equal, but they are equivalent.  For instance `f x` could be `0+x`, and `g x` could be `x+0`.

`F` returns a `nat`, and since `F` cannot look into its function argument, the returned value should be the same whether it is fed `f` or `g`.  How do I prove that?

(It is equivalent to a proof of `Proper ( f_eq ==> eq) F` where `f_eq = forall (f g:nat->nat), f x = g x`)

---

EDIT after Anton Trunov's answer: I am really asking about the [expressive power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressive_power_(computer_science)) of Coq's logic, so I would prefer not adding axioms, or a proof that this is equivalent to some weak form of some other axiom.  For instance, I think this is weaker than [Functional Extensionality](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html).

Comment: This is definitely weaker than function extensionality.  You can prove it with a sort of double-negated form of funext, that `forall f g : nat -> nat, f <> g -> ~forall x, f x = g x`; because we can decide `F f = F g`, we only need funext to prove absurdity in the case that we know `forall x, f x = g x` and also `F f <> F g`.

Answer (score 2):

The goal can be proved using functional extensionality.

```
From Coq Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.

Section Foo.
Variables f g : nat->nat.
Hypothesis Hfg : forall x, f x = g x.
Variable F : (nat->nat)->nat.

Goal F f = F g.
Proof. now apply functional_extensionality in Hfg; subst. Qed.
End Foo.
```

But is it really necessary here? The answer is "yes", because if you had the general proof, you could instantiate it for an `F` which is the identity function, and that implies `(forall x, f x = g x) -> f = g`. Or, more formally and for a more general case:

```
Axiom axiom : forall A B C (f g : A -> B) (eqv : forall x, f x = g x)
              (F : (A -> B) -> C), F f = F g.

Lemma fun_ext A B (f g : A -> B) :
  (forall x, f x = g x) -> f = g.
Proof.
  intros eqv; apply (axiom A B _ f g eqv (fun x => x)).
Qed.
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation why it is impossible without adding an axiom.  However, It blows my mind that we can't prove that two `nat`s are equal.  We can't even prove that they can't be different, for similar reasons, right?

Comment: Correct! We that would imply a weaker version of funext.

Comment: thinking some more made me realize that your axiom assumes this holds for _all_ `C`, including functions.  In the proof  you give it is instantiated with `nat->nat`, and that explains why it implies Functional Extensionality.  But my question was really about the smaller case, when `C` is `nat` (or some other inductive type with decidable equality).

Comment: You are right, I should not have generalized too much, sorry about that. I do agree with your edit in the question that it's weaker than fun. ext. Because if we had your goal proved and tried to use it to prove `f = g` (from equivalent `f` and `g`) we would need an injective `F : (nat -> nat) -> nat`, but there are no injective `F`'s whatsoever (the set of functions on naturals is strictly larger than the set of naturals).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps unsurprisingly, your goal is equivalent to a sort of function extensionality on a decidable fragment.

Note that saying `x = y` is equivalent to saying `forall P, P x <-> P y`:

```
Definition eq_alt {A} (x y : A) : Prop
  := forall (P : A -> Prop), P x <-> P y.

Lemma eq_alt_correct {A} (x y : A) : eq_alt x y <-> x = y.
Proof.
  unfold eq_alt; intuition; subst; intuition.
  apply (H (eq x)); reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Your theorem is equivalent to function extensionality where we replace equality with a sort-of decidable weakening of it, where we only consider decidable properties `P`:

```
Require Import Coq.Classes.Morphisms.

Definition equal_on_dec {A} (x y : A) : Prop
  := forall (P : A -> Prop) (P_dec : forall x, {P x} + {~P x}),
    P x <-> P y.

Section F.
  Variable F : (nat->nat)->nat.
  Definition F_ext := Proper (pointwise_relation _ eq ==> eq) F.
End F.

Lemma F_ext_iff_neg_funext
  : (forall F, F_ext F)
    <-> (forall f g : nat -> nat, (forall x, f x = g x) -> equal_on_dec f g).
Proof.
  unfold F_ext, Proper, pointwise_relation, respectful.
  split; [ intro Hfext | intro dfunext ].
  { intros f g Hfg P P_dec.
    specialize (Hfext (fun f => if P_dec f then 0 else 1) f g Hfg).
    cbn in Hfext.
    do 2 edestruct P_dec; intuition; congruence. }
  { intros F f g Hfg.
    apply (dfunext f g); [ assumption | decide equality | reflexivity ]. }
Qed.
```

So now the question is, can we prove extensionality on the decidable fragment?

---

Let's consider a simpler version.  Let's consider `F : (bool->bool)->bool`.  We can ask: can we prove that `F (fun x => if x then true else false) = F (fun x => x)`.  I think the answer here is still "no", but I don't know enough about models that invalidate function extensionality to prove it here.